# How to add providers on dynamically loaded component?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a service that create components using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` method, but now i need to pass a list of providers values to my loaded component.

I know that i can use DI to do this, but i have no idea of how do.

Comment: make use of `reflective injector` check this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/dynamic)

Comment: You can expolore this link, they have coverd all aspect of dyanamic component loading [link](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)